# Connection "default" was not found

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

## Error

`ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.`

I am receiving this error appeared when I started to use the dependency inversion principle.

## ormconfig.json

```
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 5432,
  "username": "postgres",
  "password": "docker",
  "database": "customer",
  "entities": [
    "./src/modules/**/infra/typeorm/entities/*.ts"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "./src/shared/infra/typeorm/migrations/*.ts"
  ],
  "seeds": [
    "./src/shared/infra/typeorm/seeds/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "./src/shared/infra/typeorm/migrations"
  }
}
```

## Listing this now

```
Column type for Admin#email is not defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported "reflect-metadata" on top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported).If you are using JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must explicitly provide a column type.
```

Comment: can you show your code and stack trace?Nothing help found from the configuration.

Comment: Ok @Spikie I will

Answer (score 0):

> You have to create a connection to the DB using the `createConnection`
> function.

```
const connection = await createConnection();
```

`createConnection` function returns a `connection`. use this `connection` for all your DB operations.